# Apache fails to restart after PHP installation

Tags: php, apache

I've installed Apache2 on port 81 since IIS7 uses port 80. It loads fine and show me the directory when I load it through the browser but after installing PHP5 with msi installer Apache fails to restart because of an error in httpd.conf it says it can't load the php5apache2_2.dll I get this error after doing a repair on Apache httpd.conf

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:\Webserver\php\"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\Webserver\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Here is what the error is.

> cmd line error:
>   Syntax error on line 970 of C:/Webserver/apache/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf":
>   Cannot load C:/Webserver/php/php5apache2_2.dll into server
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I googled and found a 64bit version of the PHP binary for Windows here:

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-3-2-x64-64-bit-windows-binary/

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the PHP image matches your PC - ie 32/64 bit?

Comment: i downloaded the 86x but my os is 64x the link here http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.3 I thought it wouldn't matter. I can't see a 64x version if you know one can you provide the link to for me

Comment: What matters is that the Apache exe matches the PHP version.

Comment: i downloaded this file httpd-2.0.64-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache20 which is 64x can you send me a link to 64x php msi installer please

Answer (score 0):

You need MS Visual C++ 64 bit(vc_redist.x64.exe), 64 bit Apache Binary(httpd-2.4.18-win64-VC14.zip) and 64 bit PHP (php-5.3.2-Win32-VC9-x64.zip). I tried with PHP 7 64 bit but not successful. Then used this PHP(php-5.3.2-Win32-VC9-x64.zip) it worked. All for 64 bit Windows 7
Thanks